# counting and printing each number present in a file using python

Tags: python

I have a large .dat file containing numbers

```
1 2 89 75

72 66 14 99 1022 34111

14 67 82 77 

3

7 8 9 ....
```

I want to write a program that checks for occurrence of each number say till 40000, and write out an file with the number and number of times it is present in the file.
I want the output file to be something like this

```
1 1

2 1

14 2
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This site isn't a "please code this for me" it's more a "please help me fix my code". What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: Do you have any bit of code to start with ?

Comment: fp =open('path/to/file.data'),out=open('output.dat','w') for i,l in enumerate(fp): out.write('{0} {1}'.format(i,len(l.split()))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Counter` class in the `collections` module is very useful for this sort of task:

```
import collections
import itertools

with open("file.dat") as f:
    tokens = itertools.chain.from_iterable(line.split() for line in f)
    numbers = itertools.imap(int, tokens)
    counts = collections.Counter(numbers)

for n in sorted(counts):
    print(n, counts[n])
```

Comment: +1 nice.... this can be easliy write into a file by editing--> `out=open('output.dat','w')` 
`for n in sorted(counts):` 
    `out.write('{0} {1}\n'.format(n,counts[n]))`
`out.close()`